# How to change the exit shortcut for the new Chome version?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Chrome had an exit functionality to close all tabs and windows, which was useful if you had restore previous tabs on startup selected.

This feature was bound to <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> but in a recent version of chrome it has been changed to <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd>.

Is there any way to change it back?

I want to do this partially because it's what I'm used to and partially because it interferes with other hotkeys for some extensions.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK，you can not call chrome's built-in exit api directly. As a workaround, you can try follow methods:

1. call built-in [alt f, x] use another group of keys, which call chrome's built-in exit api indirectly:
   use shortcuts mapping extensions which support synthesis keys(two non-control key, or named as chords) such as AutoControl, to map your key [ctrl shift q] to chrome's built-in [alt f, x]
2. call chrome use ahk script to quit chrome.exe from command line:
   ^+q::
   {
   ; Send the key combination to Chrome to close it gracefully
   WinClose, ahk_exe chrome.exe
   ; Optionally, you can force close Chrome by using:
   ; Process, Close, chrome.exe
   return
   }